# How to get list of email id in excel having First and Last Name?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am working on some validation process of email id through outlook. I am having First and Last name of the user. I need to generate the email id which will check first name and last name detail in outlook and get data in Microsoft excel.
I have following information.
"First" "Last" "Email address"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done, using the `Find.All(...)` basic Excel function, combined with an `=IfError(...)`, something like:

```
=IfError(Find.All(<First>;<Email>) + Find.All(<Last>;<Email>);"ok";"not ok")
```

If `Find.All(...)` does not find either first name or last name inside the e-mail address, it will result an error value. The sum of an error value and anything else just stays an error value, which you can check, using the `=IfError(...)` function.

Comment: I am new to excel and VBA, I have to fetch the email information from outlook on the basis of First and Last name. Will your code work on that? If yes can you guide me how can i use it in detail along with all the steps?